# Convert JSON to POJO class having multi words as key with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson, pojo

I have JSON like this:

```
{
    "Cell No": "",
    "Landline No": "",
    "FFCD": "243594",
    "Utility Code": "NSCH00000000022820",
    "Email ID": "",
    "Change Reason": "AC1-Default Ack Reason",
    "Category Code": "GH99"
}
```

I want to convert above json to below POJO using gson.

```
class SponsorMandate{
    private String cellNo;
    private String landlineNo;
    private String ffcd;
    private String utilityCode;
    private String emailId;
    private String changeReason;
    private String categoryCode;
}
```

My below code is not working:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonElement = gson.toJson(rowData);
System.out.println("print json" + jsonElement);

SponsorMandate sponsorMandateFileRow =
        gson.fromJson(jsonElement,SponsorMandate.class);
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @YaroslavFyodorov the OP's most likely asking for `@SerializedName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented you need to use `@SerializedName` not omly because "many word keys" but for example as `ffcd` is in different case in your JSON. Annotating  names exactly like in your JSON Gson is able to parse it:

```
@Getter @Setter
class SponsorMandate {
    @SerializedName("Cell No")
    private String cellNo;
    @SerializedName("Landline No")
    private String landlineNo;
    @SerializedName("FFCD")
    private String ffcd;
    @SerializedName("Utility Code")
    private String utilityCode;
    @SerializedName("Email ID")
    private String emailId;
    @SerializedName("Change Reason")
    private String changeReason;
    @SerializedName("Category Code")
    private String categoryCode;
}
```